# In a foreclosing Arizona home, can the bank or anyone hired by the bank access the home's interior premises without permission?

Tags: united-states, mortgage, real-estate, foreclosure, privacy

I am residing in an Arizona home that is being foreclosed upon, until the sale confirmation. Does the bank have any right to demand or assume rights to access the interior of my home while I am living in it, in order to inspect the interior of the property for the auction such as to take photos, etc?

Comment: This probably depends on where you live: which country, state/province, perhaps even city/county.

Comment: Arizona. Modified the question.

Comment: While they would not be able to do so with out permission that does not mean they need your permission.  They could get a court order allowing them to inspect the permises.

Comment: Are you talking about them forcing their way in, or arriving with no notice?  Or are they just asking if they can come and take photos?  The first seems unreasonable (likely illegal), the second more reasonable (possibly legal, though I don't know about Arizona.)

Answer (score 1):

Almost certainly no, but read your contract. As the bank has an interest in the property, they probably have a right to compel you to permit an inspection of the premises, but they must give you proper notice.

My advice, if an agent of the bank attempts to enter your home without notice or by force, call the police, call an attorney, and take down as much information as you can. Get pictures or video of the people, names if possible, record license plates, etc. Sue the crap out of them.

Talk to an attorney.